# How to pass in Apps Metadata to a Class Method?

Tags: javascript

In refactoring my Bug Report code I moved a function into a new Class 'Logger', and call the static method as seen below:

```
 $("#bugForm").submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const input = document.getElementById('nameInput');
        bugInfo = {
          "name": `[${ticket.id}] Bug report`,
          "story_type" : "Bug",
          "description": `+ ${urlHelper.zendeskTicketUrl}` + " \n" + `+ ${input.value}`,
        }
        Logger.logInfo(bugInfo).then(collapse.collapse('toggle'))
      })
    });
```

however when I run the static method I receive the following error:

```
  Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: metadata is not defined
```

Logger.js

```
 class Logger {

  constructor(settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }
    static async logInfo(data = {}) {
      console.log('Hello!')
      const url = 'exampleUrl'
      const response = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Token": `${metadata.settings.token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
      return response.json();
    }
}
```

In an attempt to fix this, I placed the following line in my code:

```
const logger = new Logger(metadata.settings);
```

And received the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Logger' before initialization
```

I originally only made the class to use its static method, does the need for metadata prevent me from doing this? Am I not using this correctly?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to have defined `metadata` anywhere. Did you mean to write `settings.metadata.token`?

Comment: well, You trying to call `Logger.logInfo` like a static method (and kinda instantiate it later) -> so rather remove `static` from method definition,  instantiate the class and use instance's methods: `const logger = new Logger(metadata.settings); logger.logInfo(bugInfo).then(collapse.collapse('toggle'))`  , as static method cannot access the `this.settings`, as 'ther's no `this` for Static method ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem the way you're passing the metadata.setting

I have changed way you use setting. Here's a working snippet

```js
$("#bugForm").submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const input = document.getElementById('nameInput');
  // logic here
  const bugInfo = {
    info: "Hello"
  }
  // changed here as I removed static
  logger.logInfo(bugInfo).then(console.log('print'))
});

class Logger {

  constructor(settings) {
    // getting the settings here and assigning it to the constructor variable
    this.settings = settings;
    console.log('hello', this.settings)
  }

  // removed static
  async logInfo(data = {}) {
    console.log('Hello!')
    const url = 'exampleUrl'
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.settings)
    const response = fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        // using it here while calling the method
        "Token": `${this.settings.token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return response.json();
  }
}


const metadata = {
  settings: {
    token: 'hello'
  }
}
const logger = new Logger(metadata.settings);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="bugForm">
  <button type="submit">
Submit
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however while the console.log prints, I still receive the error 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')'.

Comment: Did few changes. Please check that

Comment: Worked! Interesting, thanks for that.

Comment: Can you please upvote that'll be really helpful